# What's the cheapest way to get around from and to Mainland China, Taiwan, and Japan?

Tags: air-travel, japan, china, taiwan, asia

I'm a student trying to go from Canada -> China -> Taiwan -> Japan -> China -> Canada while staying in each place for at least 2-3 weeks. I've been using Google flights and rome2rio but I'm having trouble finding reasonable prices.

It seems like China -> Taiwan -> Japan -> China will cost at least $1500 CAD in airfare itself, but I don't have the experience to know where to find cheaper alternatives.

Can anyone give any suggestions? (just for airfare)

Thanks so much!

Comment: That's a pretty broad topic, involving accommodation, flights, transport, visas and more.  As per our [help], that's probably too broad, and subjective for a SE question, which is a shame.  I can recommend our [chat] though, we have a lot of guys who could give ideas

Comment: Also, if you look through some of the other questions on this site about finding cheap flights, hostels, and the like, that may help give you more ideas

Comment: Also, you might want to add some criteria around 'cheapest', otherwise the default joke answer on this site is 'have you tried hitchhiking?' (although to be fair, several of us have!)

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies! I should have specified that I am only talking about Airfare between the countries. Would you have any idea where I could find answers/information regarding that?

Comment: I'd recommend starting here, at least! http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23939/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-to-and-from-taipei-taiwan-to-shenzhen-china?rq=1

Comment: Also google flights is decent, but no site has everything. Try kayak.com, opodo, adioso, skyscanner, and consider partial or one-way flights - sometimes breaking them up works out cheaper.

Comment: Sweet, thanks so much for the suggestions! It's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

[Vanilla Air](http://www.vanilla-air.com/en/) lists a fare to Taipei from Tokyo of ¥6990 (roughly $60 USD).

Most of the low cost carriers (lcc) in Japan maintain their own ticketing infrastructure, and tickets are hard to find outside of that.  The carrier to choose for the Tokyo->China leg would depend on the city you're headed to in China; and, if you wanted to leave from Tokyo or another city.  The same site has Hong Kong fares from ¥8890 ($80 USD); but, if you want to go to the mainland, you'd need to find a different carrier.

(edited to add)
Vanilla Air has some [not-so-flattering reviews](http://www.japanlccs.com/p/vanilla-air.html), so, caveat emptor and all that.  The linked site has some good English information on all of the LCC in Japan.